# What is the graph of a hyperbola where the two cones are split through the middle?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, dual-cone

So If you have two cones stacked on top of each other like you see in a normal conic section, and the cones are split perfectly in two (1/2 of the diameter of the cone's base), how would you graph the hyperbola?  For a normal hyperbola you would have the cones split in a way that the two parts of the hyperbola can't touch each other, but what if they went through the central point?

Thanks!

Comment: The result is a "degenerate" hyperbola consisting of crossed lines. See Wikipedia's ["Degenerate conic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic) entry. (BTW: The cones need not be "split through the middle"; this degeneracy only requires that the cutting plane pass through the common vertex of the cones.)

Comment: Oh okay.  That's really useful, the stuff I always wonder in my mathematics classes are never actually covered.

Comment: Math classes can't cover everything. I got started in mathematics research by investigating topics that seemed overlooked in my high school courses. (As a matter of fact, my first personal research project involved conic sections.) Stay curious! :)

Comment: @blue Will do, thanks!

Comment: @Blue: That “comment” of your is an answer. Would have preferred upvoting it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer, as requested ...

---

The result is a "degenerate" hyperbola consisting of crossed lines. See Wikipedia's ["Degenerate conic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic) entry.

BTW, the cones need not be "split through the middle"; this degeneracy only requires that the cutting plane pass through the common vertex of the cones.